# NextJS Redirect to a folder containing static page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to Link from a nextJS page to a folder containing static build html page, placed in the root.
Is it possible to use `Link` or `async redirect()`? Or is there any other appropriate way ?

Like `<Link href='/anotherStaticBuild'> Click here </Link>`

Folder structure

```
 - public
 - pages
 - anotherStaticBuild(not-next-app)
    - build
    - index.html
 - next.config.js
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to redirect but not directly to the static page you would have to export the page as a string and load
it in a component called within a page inside the pages folder and then redirect to that page.

(Note :- but u still can find a way around by importing the static page into a component
that is called from a page and adding it to the DOM via the dangerouslySetInnerHTML
attribute but cannot redirect directly to it.)

You can check the example given below :-
import DOMPurify from "dompurify";
const htmlContent = `<h1>John Doe</h1>`;
const myPage = DOMPurify.sanitize(htmlContent);
const App = () => <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: myPage }} />

Comment: And if is "static page" is a PDF file inside the/public directory?

I tried to use [redirects](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects) inside next.config.js without success. I recived an error:

`destination is missing, invalid field: target for route`